# Dynamically allocating and accessing an array of pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

For example I have

```
*line[30];
```

I want to allocate a string 81 characters for each pointer. How can I do that and in which way can I access the second string for example to use it in a printf?

Also what about `**a`, is it an equivalent?

I'm a newbie and this may be an easy question, but I'm eager to learn. Thank you very much!

Comment: `line[1]` is the second string, provided you've allocated and populated the memory for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code snippet will help you.

```
#define MAX_LINES 30
#define MAX_CHARS 81
...
char * line[MAX_LINES];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < MAX_LINES; i++)
{
    line[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_CHARS);
}
```

Use the same `for` loop for accessing each line. `line[1]` will access second string (ie line).

Answer (score 3):

`I want to allocate a string 81 characters for each pointer`

Since you know the exact size you want, you can do this statically:

```
char line[30][81];
```

This gives you 30 arrays of 81 characters.

```
strcpy(line[0], "hello");
strcpy(line[1], "world");

printf("%s\n", line[1]);  // prints the second string
```

Comment: +1. Always prefer this to `malloc` unless you actually need it.

Comment: +1. The best way to avoid problems with memory management is to avoid memory management.  Of course, beyond a certain size, you'll need to go the dynamic allocation route, but for this problem it isn't necessary.